# Lost permission after chmod command

Tags: linux, permissions, chmod

I accidentally executed the following command:

```
chmod -rwxr-xr-x folder_name
```

And after the command, I was not able to access the folder `folder_name`. I'm wondering if there is any way that I could recover the full permission to the folder.

Comment: Please note that Stack Overflow is for programming questions and not questions about using or setting up Linux. Please review [What topics can I ask here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) for more details. Question may be appropriate for [Super User](http://superuser.com) or [Unix & Linux](http://unix.stackexchange.com) but do check their help before posting.

Comment: Just change the permissions back to what they were originally or at least to a level that the current user can access it. The latter would be like: `chmod u+rwx folder_name`

Comment: @kaylum Sorry I should have checked for a better place for the post. Quick question if it is okay: Should I use the flag -R in this case? Thank you!

Comment: There is no need for `-R` because your original command did not have it.